# Story identification movie with teens having superpowers

Tags: story-identification, powers

Don't Exactly remember the whole movie.

To start with, there are some teens (4/5), standing at top of cliff, then suddenly starts jumping when they reach down there is party going down there in the ground. The teens are shown to have the super natural abilities.

Then somewhere in between dispute arises midst two teens from group (Surely villain and hero)

Next scene I remember is when one teen (not with powers) from group comes to drop his Girl Friend at her Dorm and when leaves on his bike the villain comes and throws him from his bike.

The climax is having a fight between those two on his 18th birthday, it is set up near an old barn on the night, when hero is about to get defeated his powers awoke and he thrashes the other.

The movie was setup in nicely and was having good vfx, so I guess it could have released anywhere between 2005-2009.

Need to identify this really bad, friends and me watched it some 6-7 years ago and we have all forgotten now. This one's for the Friend zone. cheers

Comment: I don't know if this is because this is written by someone who is not a native English speaker, or if it's for other reasons, but I am not clear on what some of these descriptions of the scenes are trying to describe.  (Also, it helps if you can tell us other facts about the movie: When do you think it was released, or at least when did you see it?  What country was it produced in?  What language was it in?  Any facts like that can help.)

Comment: @Tango see the edited question

Comment: Still not sure.  Who jumps? All teens or one or two?  Do they jump off the cliff or just jumping up and down?  Who is the person with the 18th birthday?  The guy with the girlfriend, or the other guy?  And is the guy with the girlfriend the hero?  I'll be glad to tighten it up, but I'm not sure about these points and they create a bit of confusion so I wouldn't know for sure how to edit it and keep accuracy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for [The Covenant](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0475944/?ref_=nv_sr_1).  This follows four teenagers who have a family background of witchcraft.  They receive some power at puberty but do not receive their full power until the age of 18.  The antagonist is another teenager with similar heritage whose grandparent was kicked out of the town.

The first scene in the movie is the four protagonists (Caleb, Pogue, Tyler and Reid) jumping off of a cliff to join a party.

The climax of the movie is the fight between Caleb and Chase at the old barn.  The fight ends when two events occur:  Caleb turns 18 and Caleb's father gives power to his son.  After both of these occur, Caleb easily wins the fight.

Although not exact, the other scenes you mention also occur.  The four protagonists consult the family history for clues about Chase.  Pogue gets flipped of his bike by Chase.  Reid and Caleb get into a fight - although neither is at full power, Caleb is clearly stronger.